# Processing Camera stream in Opencv, pushing it over RTMP (NGINX RTMP Module) using FFMPEG

Tags: opencv, nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, http-live-streaming

Output video:
https://youtu.be/VxfoBQjoY6E

**Explanation:**

I want to: Process camera stream in Opencv and push it over to RTMP server. I already have NGINX (RTMP module) set up and I have tested streaming videos with both RTMP (Flash Player) and HLS.

I am reading the frames in a loop and using 'subprocess' in python to execute ffmpeg command. Here's the command I am using:

```
command = [ffmpeg,
    '-y',
    '-f', 'rawvideo',
    '-vcodec','rawvideo',
    '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
    '-s', dimension,
    '-i', '-',
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
    '-preset', 'ultrafast',
    '-f', 'flv',
    'rtmp://10.10.10.80/live/mystream']


import subprocess as sp
...
proc = sp.Popen(command, stdin=sp.PIPE,shell=False)
...
proc.stdin.write(frame.tostring()) #frame is read using opencv
```

**Problem:**

I can see the stream fine but it freezes and resumes frequently. Here's the output of FFMPEG terminal log:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
frame=  117 fps= 16 q=22.0 size=     344kB time=00:00:04.04 bitrate= 697.8kbits/s speed=0.543x
```

It mentions speed at the end. I believe it should be close to 1x. I am not sure how to achieve that.

And I am on the same network as server, I can post my python code if required. Need some ffmpeg guru to give me some advise.

**EDIT**

My input fps is actually ~3.
With `'-use_wallclock_as_timestamps', '1'` I can see in the log that speed is close to 1x.
But HLS is not streaming live there's ~2 min delay, it halts and . Chris's advise partially worked. I am not sure where exactly is the problem, I am starting to believe it has something to do with nginx-rtmp module.

Here's the final output, on left it's flash and on right it's hls. I am showing the ffmpeg options at the end.
https://youtu.be/jsm6XNFOUE4

Comment: Hi sir! I also have the same question that want to send the mat to nginx server, but how to write the mat/images to the output stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar issues before when streaming either raw video (like you are) or from an MJPEG source. There are two input options to try with ffmpeg to get it to stay at 1x speed:

#### Option 1

```
ffmpeg -re -i <rest of input options>
```

`-re` tells ffmpeg to read at the native input rate

#### Option 2

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i <rest of input options>
```

`-use_wallclock_as_timestamps` tells ffmepg to just take each frame as it comes in, take the system time, and make that the timestamp. I've found this option most effective when the speed slows right down.

#### Do regardless

Ensure you're encoding at a constant framerate. ffmpeg can get a bit finicky when the framerate varies, so on the output options, use `-r 25` (replacing the 25 for your desired output framerate) to force ffmpeg to use a static framerate out

Comment: I tried with using -re and -r but it didn't work. And according to the following guide, -re is not required when streaming form live device. I'll check your proposed solution soon. And yes frame-rate varies and I think I can somehow keep it constant.
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide

Comment: with wallclock as timestamp and -re the speed is 1x but hls is not really streaming live. I have edited the question above and have added the output video and ffmpeg commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use the MoviePy module (which I found great btw). Have a look at the [MoviePy Video Writer](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py). It is supposed to write to local files but you can also use it with rtmp streams by adding `-f flv` at the end of the command to specify the output format. To write a frame to the stream, just use the method `write_frame(your_frame)`. It worked pretty well for me

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and found ffmpeg can not fill the gaps automaticly, so when you feed ffmpeg with 3 fps, the client will still play at 25 fps, so the client will need to cache a lot frames before play and then play it at fast speed, then stop to cache frames again

So it is easy just fill the gap when you feed ffmpeg with code like this

```
timeStart = get_time_seconds()
count = 0
some loop:
  frame = getimage()
  targetCount = (get_time_seconds()-timeStart)*25
  repeatCount = targetCount - count
  loop for repeatCount times:
     proc.stdin.write(frame.tostring()) 
  count = targetCount
```